# What does the $ in an excel reference mean?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm learning how to use Excel by fire. I have been given a spreadsheet. In that spreadsheet is a formula that looks like this:

```
=(($J$1 + $L$2)*$D$5
```

I'm not familiar with that syntax. Is that the same as:

```
=(($J1 + $L2)*$D5
```

I understand that `$[Letter][Number]` references a cell. However, I haven't seen the syntax that uses two dollar signs `$[Letter]$[Number]`. What does that mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [absolute references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-538396b3-990e-4b44-9d9c-28b4151d7d21), they never change.

You can make it so the column never changes `$C` or the row never changes `$2` or both never change `$C$2`.

This is useful when you have a constant you want to apply to a bunch of formulas that refer to something else - you can drag it down and the absolute reference won't "walk" out of range. see -

[image]